# How to add a %VAR% to the Windows system PATH within a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have been searching for a way to add a %var% to the system PATH in Windows 7.  I am currently doing the following:

`setx PATH "%PATH%;%PATH1%;%PATH2%;" /m`

This works as expected.  It adds whatever is in those system variables to the Path.  However, I want to add the actual string '%PATH1%' to the system Path so if I make changes to the %PATH1% variable, it gets reflected in the PATH.

How do I do this?

EDIT

Currently, in Windows, I have these system variables:

`Path1 = c:\path`
`Path2 = c:\another\path`

I am using a batch process to create these system variables.  I want to add these new variables to the PATH like this:

`PATH = <other paths>;%PATH1%;%PATH2%`

Currently, it shows up as:

`PATH = <other paths>;c:\path; c:\another\path`

My reasoning is that I want to edit the system variable and have the PATH updated at the same time.

Comment: Show more of your problem, as it seems that your approach of modifying the path variable is not the best solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `%var%` literally, but that will not work as you expect.

Then cmd.exe tries to find files in a directory called `%var%` which normally will not exist on your system.
It will not expand `%var%` inside your path variable.

If you try it (on the console) and a batch exists in C:\temp with the name "myTest.bat"

```
set path=%path%;%^var%
set path
set var=C:\temp
set path
myTest
```

The output will be

```
C:\windows;....;%var%
C:\windows;....;%var%
Can't find internal or external command "mytest"
```

Comment: Would it be better to use the Windows Powershell?

Comment: What the Powershell has to do with the path expansion? Perhaps you should edit your question to explain more of your current problem